# Enabling HTTPS for a Azure blob static website

Tags: azure, web, certificate, azure-blob-storage, custom-domain

I have an Azure storage account with a static website on the blob service enabled. I also have configured custom domain for my blob service. To be able to serve my website over HTTPS on the custom domain I need to somehow apply my certificate. How can I do it?

p.s.
I don't want no CDN

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> To be able to serve my website over HTTPS on the custom domain I need
>   to somehow apply my certificate. How can I do it?

Unfortunately it is not possible as of writing this answer because Azure Storage still doesn't have the ability to allow you to bring your own certificates. You will need to use CDN if you want HTTPS enabled custom domain mapped to your static website hosted in Azure Blob Storage.

From this [`link`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-blob-static-website#mapping-a-custom-domain-to-a-static-website-url):

> It's easier to enable HTTP access for your custom domain, because
>   Azure Storage natively supports it. **To enable HTTPS, you'll have to
>   use Azure CDN because Azure Storage does not yet natively support
>   HTTPS with custom domains**. see Map a custom domain to an Azure Blob
>   Storage endpoint for step-by-step guidance.

Answer (score -1):

You can use an application gateway instead of CDN, here is a recipe:
https://github.com/easkerov/azure-sa-custom-domain-ssl-sample